# Angularjs: how to make directive interpolate trying while processing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

While repeating thru angulajs collection, the photos directive does not interpolate inner loop (see code as follows):

```
                    <tr ng-repeat="typology in accident.popover.typology">
                        <td class="key" ng-if="typology.photo">
                            <photos photoid="{{typology.photo}}" size="256px"
                                list="[{file:'rsc/accident/thumb/{{accident.id}}/Incrustation/{{typology.photo}}'}]">
                            </photos>
                        </td>
```

Photo directive keeps unprocessed (not interpolated) 'file' value.

[edit]
The directive as follows:

```
app.directive("photos", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            "photoid": "@",
            "scrollable": "@",
            "size": "@",
            "height":"@",
            "list": "=",
            "inline": "@",
            "extension": "@",
            "class": "@"
        },
        template: 
        '<div id="photos{{photoid}}" class="scroller {{class}}" ng-class="[{{scrollable}}]" ng-style="{display:list.length==1?\'inline-block\':\'block\', width: list.length==1?\'{{size||\'171px\'}}\':\'auto\', height: \'{{height||size||\'171px\'}}\'}">\n\
            <div ng-repeat="p in list"\n\
                ng-style="{\'background-image\': \'url({{p.file}}.thumb.{{extension||\'jpg\'}})\', width: \'{{size||\'171px\'}}\', height: \'{{height||size||\'171px\'}}\'}"\n\
                ng-click="$parent.$parent.openPopoverImageViewer(\'#photos{{photoid}}\', {{$index}})">\n\
                <div>{{p.text}}</div>\n\
            </div>\n\
        </div>'
    };
});
```

Comment: You'll have to share more code - the directive definition etc.

Comment: I added the directive code @IvanKovachev

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console and are you sure the model that you repeat on is populated with data?

Comment: Does {{accident.id}} exist as a property?  Can you post the JSON you're using as your model?

Comment: Yep all properties exist. Json record is huge and won't bring anything to the matter.

Comment: suggest you create a demo. Since you have isolated scope and are using `list:'='` there would be no reason to interpolate it. Might be able to use `ng-init` to create interpolated list array

Answer (score 0):

Parse the list value as JSON in the link function- its currently a string and not a JSON object(JSON.parse() wont work in IE < IE8, so you may want to use some lib for this):

```
app.directive("photos", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            "photoid": "@",
            "scrollable": "@",
            "size": "@",
            "height":"@",
            "inline": "@",
            "extension": "@",
            "class": "@"
        },
        template: 
        '<div id="photos{{photoid}}" class="scroller {{class}}" ng-class="[{{scrollable}}]" ng-style="{display:list.length==1?\'inline-block\':\'block\', width: list.length==1?\'{{size||\'171px\'}}\':\'auto\', height: \'{{height||size||\'171px\'}}\'}">\n\
            <div ng-repeat="p in list"\n\
                ng-style="{\'background-image\': \'url({{p.file}}.thumb.{{extension||\'jpg\'}})\', width: \'{{size||\'171px\'}}\', height: \'{{height||size||\'171px\'}}\'}"\n\
                ng-click="$parent.$parent.openPopoverImageViewer(\'#photos{{photoid}}\', {{$index}})">\n\
                <div>{{p.text}}</div>\n\
            </div>\n\
        </div>'
    },
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.list = JSON.parse(attrs.list);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following solution - move the definition of photos list to the controller:

**HTML:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="typology in accident.popover.typology">
    <td class="key" ng-if="typology.photo">
        <photos photoid="{{typology.photo}}" size="256px"
           list="getPhotoList(accident.id, typology.photo)">
         </photos>
   </td>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.getPhotoList = function(id, name) {
   return [{file:'rsc/accident/thumb/' + id + '/Incrustation/' + name}]};
```